# PHP uploaded file not saved, but says it did

Tags: php

I have this PHP code:

```
if (isset($_FILES["ufile"]["name"])){              //if file was chosen

    $allowed =  array('pdf');
    $filename = $_FILES['ufile']['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {                //only allowed filetype is PDF
        echo 'Nevybral jste soubor PDF. <a style="color:blue; text-decoration:underline;" onclick="window.history.back()">Vraťte se na předchozí stránku.</a>';
    }
    else {                                         //if everything OK, proceed to save the file
        $jmeno=  "pdf".date("dmY").".pdf";         //for example pdf17052014.pdf (works fine)
        $path="depository/".$jmeno;                //depository has chmod 777
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $path)){ //if moved to depository, echo -all fine-
            echo "<font color=green>The file was uploaded</font>";
            include "friends.php";
            mysql_connect("$Dhost", "$Duser", "$Dpass");
            mysql_select_db("$Dbname");
            $filtr = mysql_real_escape_string(br2nl($_POST["nadpis"]));
            $filtrB = mysql_real_escape_string(br2nl($_POST["zprava"]));
            $provedu="insert into usneseni (autor, cas, nazev, text, odkaz) values ('".$_SESSION["jmeno"]."',".time().",'".$filtr."', '".$filtrB."', '".$jmeno."')";
            $vysledek=mysql_query("$provedu") or die(mysql_error()." <font color=red>Nepodařilo se zapsat do databáze</font>");  
            mysql_close();      
        }
        else {
            echo $_FILES['ufile']['error'];
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it,  it shows **"The file was uploaded"**. Then I write its name to the database, which works fine. But when I take a look into the "depository", the file is not there. Depository has chmod 777. The code doesn't show any error. I don't know why does it happen.

Comment: You can use this file upload control http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Comment: try to put like this and check `$path="/depository/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the directory depository in the same folder as your main script or is it in the same folder as your upload script you presented to us?

How do you make sure, that there is now uploaded file? (at some ftp clients you have to update the directory to see new files.)

I took your script and used it on my server. It works for me. I used `@date` to suppress warnings, because often times it throws an error, when timezone is not correctly specified. Another way would be to use  `date_default_timezone_set(UTC);//Use your own timezone here.`. As long as date throws errors, your filestring might not be build correctly.

Did you try `var_dump($_FILES);`?

Comment: It is in the same directory. The path goes (Root)/page/depository/, the script is in "page"

Comment: I added some new questions for you

Comment: I used @date and now it works. Don't really know why but thank you!